# The difference between two classes of a function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, integral-domain

I have a function f. What is the difference between the below cases:

1. a$\in$ $C^0$[0,1]$\cap$$C^1(0,1]$
2. a$\in$ $C^1$[0,1]

I know that $C^0$[0,1] means that the function is continuous. But what is the difference between these two domains?

Comment: The first one means that at $0$ the function is continuous but not necessarily $C^1$.

Comment: More specifically, the former means the function is continuous in a neighborhood of $0$, while the latter says it is continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, you can not be differentiable at $0$, not for the second. There is a common counterexample given by
$$x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$$